# Blender 2.91 - Installing Add-Ons via the Python API

Tags: python, rendering, network

i'm trying to create a crowdrender node on my headless server running Debian 10 and it has no form of GUI, so i'm stuck installing the Add-On throug the Python API. However, i can't find any guides that aren't outdated and i'm mostly met with error returns (not excluding the possibility i've messed it up myself, but i can hardly imagine at this early stage).

I would be very grateful if someone could point me to the proper commands needed, thank you in advance. Cheers.

Comment: For reference, you don't actually have to use Python; you can just copy the addon folder/file to the `scripts/addons` directory and pass `--addons your_addon_name` when you start Blender and it will start with the addon enabled.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try that!